# How to setup Elasticsearch for your tests using build.gradle

Tags: elasticsearch, gradle, build.gradle

So, I have been trying to write JUnit tests for my APIs which interact with Elasticsearch. This is like Integration test where I need to setup Elasticsearch before I can run my code.

For all the tests, I need to create a test task which will do following:

1. Download the zip from

   ```
   compile group: 'org.elasticsearch.distribution.zip', name: 'elasticsearch', version: '6.1.1', ext: 'pom'
   ```
2. Run elasticsearch executable present in /bin of unzipped file. When running this executable, take as argument `elasticsearch.yml` file in the command.
3. Once the all the tests are run, stop the elasticsearch executable, and clean the zipped folder.

Things that I can improve is that if zip file is already present in my gradle cache, then don't download it again and again.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following dependency to your `build.gradle` file

```
configurations {
  elasticDist
}
...
dependencies { 
  elasticDist group: 'org.elasticsearch.distribution.zip', name: 'elasticsearch', version: '6.1.2', ext: 'zip'
}
```

Add tasks to unzip and cleanup, setup dependencies

```
task unzip(type: Copy) {
  // to download distribution
  dependsOn configurations.elasticDist

  from { // use of closure defers evaluation until execution time
    configurations.elasticDist.collect { zipTree(it) }
  }

  into file("${buildDir}/your/destination")
}

task cleanElastic(type:Delete) {
   delete file("${buildDir}/your/destination")
}

test.dependsOn('unzip')
test.finalizedBy('cleanElastic')
```

Using your test framework of choice, configure `setUp` and `tearDown` to start and stop elastic respectively.

Comment: You don't know how much I owe you for this. I have been struggling this to get things ready for my tests for days, and elasticsearch community was not helping me. Thank You.